# Flash Air with Flash Professional CS6, Alert window

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am writing an app in Flash AIR

I want to have it such that when I press the back button, an alert window will
confirm whether I wish to exit the application, with options Y/N.

But I do not know how to make an Android Alert Window. Googling has brought up many native extensions of which I do not know how to use.

Any help? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use a native extension.  There's a free one below with a detailed tutorial:-

http://juankpro.com/wordpress/2012/06/17/using-the-local-notification-ane-on-ios/

alternatively the CoreMobile extension from MilkmanGames is nice and easy and comes with a full sample application if you're prepared to spend some $

http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/